# How to write the texts in top right side of the box in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, textarea

```
<table> 
<tr> <td> Name </td> 
     <td> <input type="text" name="name"> </td> 
</tr>

<tr> <td> Comments </td> 
     <td> <textarea style="width: 300px; height:300px;" name="comment">Something</textarea></td> 
</tr>
```

Above code will form a simple form in Web page. However the  text "comments" doesn't inline in appropriate section of the table. I want this text to be in top of the box however it shows in the middle of the box. Is there any method to make it in the correct place that I want to so that the form looks standard. Is it CSS that I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top` style to `<td>` element, i.e.:

```
 <td style="vertical-align:top"> Comments </td>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aL7EP/)

[See this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for documentation for `vertical-algin` property, including list of values other than `top` you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply a class, e.g:

```
tr td:first-child {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

## [Per this example](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/75F3b/)

If you also want to right align your items, [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/75F3b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS for this, try following code,

```
<table> 
<tr> <td> Name </td> 
     <td> <input type="text" name="name"> </td> 
</tr>

<tr> <td style = "vertical-align:top;"> Comments </td> 
     <td> <textarea style="width: 300px; height:300px;" name="comment">Something</textarea></td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add valign attribute to the td.

```
<td valign="top"> Comments </td>
```

[See this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) for vertical align documentation